# Hibernate and @AttributeOverride

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Person extends BaseEntity {
     private String name;
     ...
}

@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", @Column = (name = "idStudent"))
public class Student extends Person {
    private float avgGrades;
    ...
}
```

I would like to override ID property so in Student table there would be a `idStudent` column instead of `id`. Unfortunately, the code above doesn't work. It looks like `@AttributeOverride` only works for the class you extending (and no one step further). Is there any way to override attribute name in situation I've descried (override attribute in class which exteds our class being extended) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is very easy to understand, if you know what the default inheritance type is: `SINGLE_TABLE`.

That means all entities that extending `Person` are in the same table. And thus `Person` already defines the ID column. Because you would otherwise violate the contract of the primary key column of your `Person` table.

I cite the JavaDoc of `@AttributeOverride` as well:

> May be applied to an entity that extends a mapped superclass or to an embedded field or property to override a basic mapping or id mapping defined by the mapped superclass or embeddable class (or embeddable class of one of its attributes).

It always helps to read the JavaDoc first, before asking questions here.

What can you do about it? Make your `Person` a `@MappedSuperclass` (or create a `BasePerson` that is one).

Comment: I know Hibernate inheritence types - I skipped it in my example to make it as minimalistic as possible (also I thought it's irrelevant here - am I wrong? I use TABLE_PER_CLASS). Actually anottating Person with @MappedSuperclass worked - thanks. A little stupid of me - in my real project, inside Person there are some mappings and I'd originally thought that because of this Person cannot be MappedSuperclass.

Comment: The inheritance type was relevant, as I would not had to write the first two paragraphs than. Although as you can see from the JavaDoc it is not relevant for `AttributeOverride`.